# how to create new python column based on custom function on another column

Tags: python, apply

### Please, I would appreciate any input to this problem.

I have this table below

[image]

I want to create a new column "cap" based on the ID column.

steps:
Get all unique ID values with their counts
if the count is greater than or equal to 4, return A
if the count is greater than 2 and less than 4, return B
if the count is less than or equal to 2, return C

[image]

I need a new way to solve the problem above

This is what I was trying out though I get an error.

```
cnt = pd.DataFrame(train['ID'].value_counts())

def cap_fnx(data, cnt):  
  for y in range(len(cnt['ID'].unique())):
    if data['ID'] == cnt.index[y]:
      if cnt.loc[y].ID >= 4:
        return 'A'
      if cnt.loc[y].ID > 2 and cnt.loc[y].ID < 4:
        return 'B'
      if cnt.loc[y].ID <= 2:
        return 'C'

train['cap'] = train.apply(cap_fnx, args=(cnt))
```

This is a sample of the data;

```
train = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','score'])
train.loc[0] = np.array([11, 0.11])
train.loc[1] = np.array([11,4.64 ])
train.loc[2] = np.array([12,3.39])
train.loc[3] = np.array([11,0.44 ])
train.loc[4] = np.array([17,4.83])
train.loc[5] = np.array([17,2.22])
train.loc[6] = np.array([11,1.18])
train.loc[7] = np.array([13,4.74])
train.loc[8] = np.array([12,2.13])
train.loc[9] = np.array([8,0.44])
train.loc[10] = np.array([17,1.73])
```

Comment: This seems to be wrong `if data['ID'] == cnt.index[y]:` because `data['ID']` gives you the complete column. Post the error trace plz

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: You need to share the data for people to help you with ease.

Comment: i added the data to the post